# Disallow certain user names?

Tags: feature-request, display-names

On Server Fault we have noticed a lot of people naming their accounts Server fault, Moderator, or new today [Deleted account](https://serverfault.com/users/71634/deleted-account). This could lead to some confusion, and I would like to request they be blocked. Also though I haven't seen it, I wonder if someone could sign up with an expletive or non-appropriate username?

Comment: What's your feature request?

Comment: @mark to place a blacklist of usernames.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you think a particular user name is offensive or confusing, just flag one of the user's posts with a message to the moderator.

They have all the tools required to deal with such behavior.

The trouble with a black list, is that people can constantly figure ways around it. `Servar Fault`, `Mod`, `Administrator`, `Owner`, `Fu*k` and so on....

Comment: I agree, but it can't really hurt to put one in I would assume, it would at-least stop *some* of it.

Comment: @Jacob If certain patterns become common and cause excess work for the moderators, they will implement filtering.  Until then, though, they'll just work the moderators like dogs to fix the problem.

Comment: @Jacob, we have spent so much work on the moderator UI. At the moment there are *only* 2 flags on SF. SF could easily handle many, many more flags. The mods on SF certainly have the bandwidth to deal with this.

Comment: @Jacob - I saw the flag for 'deleted account' in the system, so the system does work :) To be honest though it doesn't happen too often.

Comment: Haha. lol @ `Servar Fault`