# Disallow user names which result in unclickable links

Tags: feature-request, users, display-names

**This is not a duplicate of [Why are usernames allowed to be composed entirely of non-visible Unicode characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact) as that simply asks why this ability exists. This is a feature request asking for this ability to be removed. [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83348/295232) by former employee @waffles doesn't really apply either; while I do agree that some problematic usernames can only be detected by humans (especially when they depend on context), this type of usernames *can* be blocked automatically.**

Consider [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55542334/4751173).

> [image]

It's made by a [user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318054/%cd%8f%cd%8f%cd%8f) who decided to put some strange characters in their username, which results in them not being rendered. Where can you click to navigate to that user?

...

It took me a while to realize you can click the (blank) avatar as well, I've never used that feature before.

I propose to disallow usernames like this; there should always be something of a name to click on. I mean, it's called a 'display name', so it should be ... displayed, right?

The characters are from the [Latin-1 Supplement](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/latin_supplement/index.htm), alternating between a [LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE (U+00CD)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00cd/index.htm) and a [SINGLE SHIFT THREE (U+008F)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/008f/index.htm). The first one is unusual but rather innocent (just a vowel with a diacritical mark), the second one is 'suspicious' in as far as Unicode characters can be like that. The Unicode code point is still visible in the URL, encoded as `%cd%8f%cd%8f%cd%8f`; their username has been reset networkwide by an unknown ♦ moderator (whoever it was, thank you!).

Comment: Their username seems to have been reset network-wide now (their network profile is still cached), but I managed to capture what their username used to be in Unicode hex: `CD 8F CD 8F CD 8F`

Comment: Heh, I was just editing that into the post :) Thanks to whoever did that!

Comment: Would it be simpler to say that certain characters (such as `%`) shouldn't be allowed in usernames? It might get complicated to assemble a list of every possible character combination that could result in something strange.

Comment: @JasonBassford that character is not part of the user name but part of the escape sequence used to show the invisible characters in the link.

Comment: @MEEthesetupwizard Okay—then what *was* the specific character, or combination of characters, in the username that actually caused the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are usernames allowed to be composed entirely of non-visible Unicode characters?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact)

Comment: I can't find it now, but I remember some official guidance that if a user's name is problematic (e.g. because it's completely blank), moderators should reset it and contact the user to explain.

Comment: @JasonBassford The thing is, it isn't a specific character. For example, combining diacritics are fine if they're used over a letter, but a username consisting solely of combining diacritics are not. It's very difficult to identify all problematic names programmatically. It would be possible to identify usernames that are rendered as blank on a specific rendering engine, however, so it would be a good idea if the system did that for some sensible default rendering engine.

Comment: @Gilles Not a duplicate. That is a question asking why it exists; this one is a feature request asking for it to be removed.

Comment: @Glorfindel Do you consider [non-typable user names](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/175715/%e1%86%bc%e1%86%ba%e1%86%bc) under the umbrella of this request?, how do we reply in comments (with at, at least on mobile). I've *seen* the invisible person (people) before, and quickly realized that the *invisible* avatar could be clicked on; replying to these people is another matter. If the UI would accept "[%e1%86%bc%e1%86%ba%e1%86%bc](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/175715/%e1%86%bc%e1%86%ba%e1%86%bc)" as their name it would be inconvenient.

Comment: @Rob When users attempt to type a reply comment on a post where someone with a username containing non-ASCII characters has commented, they show up immediately as an autocomplete choice, without having to type the first character of their username.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55213791/3648282) and see that you can't reply to user ᆼᆺᆼ by using autocompletion. Another example is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55651259/3648282) where user icza 'at replied' (possibly by copy/paste, we don't know it was by autocomplete); what works on your browser isn't working on Firefox Android (but works fine with ***your*** name, and @Glorfindel's).

Comment: Yes, I can reply to them with autocompletion using `@ [tab] [space]`. It works fine for me.

Comment: It doesn't look like the name has been reset. I still reproduce this on the user's account for both Stack Overflow, and the Stack Exchange network profile.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog #0) Tab [doesn't work on Opera](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158726/pressing-tab-doesnt-expand-autocompleted-chat-names-in-opera?rq=1), #1) You know there's no TAB on *most* Android keyboards, #2) It's  [marked here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177621/using-so-on-a-mobile-device/231607#231607) status-by-design for mobile (but apparently not mobile desktop for some browsers), #3) This [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/168118/dealing-with-difficult-usernames-in-targeted-comments) marked status-completed is arguably *close enough*.

Comment: @Rob It's also possible by typing the @ sign then tapping on the username, at least in Mobile Chrome. Also, on the app, there is an explicit "reply" feature that allows you to prefill usernames.

Comment: @CodyGray Maybe their SO profile was missed when a CM reset it network-wide. Also, network profiles are cached, though this one may be drawing info from SO.

Comment: @SonictheWizardWerehog #4) This [says at-TAB doesn't work for Unicode name **editors**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259651/please-allow-non-unicode-named-editors-be-pinged-with-autocomplete) and it's not status-completed, but [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/112360/is-the-reply-in-a-comment-to-the-editor-of-a-post-broken) says it's by-design, then was completed, #6) etc. - It's dead @ JimtheWizardWherehog :)

Comment: @CodyGray It most definitely was reset; an SU mod confirmed in the SU mod room that they weren't able to see it at that time. It looks like the user set it again on each site. I should have manually crawled all of those into WayBackMachine...

Comment: Oh yeah. Sorry, @Sonic. A mod did reset it ~6 hours ago, but the user has since changed it back. I should have checked the history.

Comment: I'm 99.999% sure this was asked before as feature request. Quick search didn't find it, will try again later. However, agree it's not a dupe of [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196407/why-are-usernames-allowed-to-be-composed-entirely-of-non-visible-unicode-charact). (If it gets closed ping me and I'll reopen.)

Comment: Related: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/83348/364003) by waffles. Is that what you meant @ShadowWizard?

Comment: @MEE not a dupe either, just related too.

Comment: And their username is reset **again**.

Comment: @ShadowWizard well it explains why this problem will only be solvable by mod reset. (and some private messages)

Comment: He did reset it again. I've undone it and suspended the user.

Comment: @DavidPostill They did it again, it would appear, at least on SO.